# How to bind lifetimes of Futures to fn arguments in Rust

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, rust, future

Im trying to write a simple `run_transaction` function for the Rust MongoDB Driver

This function tries to execute a transaction through the mongo db client and retries the transaction if it encounters a retryable error

Here is a minimum reproducible example of the function.

```rust
use mongodb::{Client, Collection, ClientSession};
use mongodb::bson::Document;
use std::future::Future;

pub enum Never {}

fn main() {
    run_transaction(|mut session| async move {
        let document = collection().find_one_with_session(None,  None, &mut session).await?.unwrap();
        let r: Result<Document, TransactionError<Never>> = Ok(document);
        return r;
    });
}

fn collection() -> Collection<Document> {
    unimplemented!();
}

fn client() -> Client {
    unimplemented!();
}

pub enum TransactionError<E> {
    Mongodb(mongodb::error::Error),
    Custom(E)
}

impl<T> From<mongodb::error::Error> for TransactionError<T> {
    fn from(e: mongodb::error::Error) -> Self {
        TransactionError::Mongodb(e)
    }
}

// declaration
pub async fn run_transaction<T, E, F, Fut>(f: F) -> Result<T, TransactionError<E>> 
  where for<'a>
        F: Fn(&'a mut ClientSession) -> Fut + 'a,
        Fut: Future<Output = Result<T, TransactionError<E>>> { 

  
  let mut session = client().start_session(None).await?;
  session.start_transaction(None).await?;
      
  'run: loop {
    let r = f(&mut session).await;

    match r {
      Err(e) => match e {
        TransactionError::Custom(e) => return Err(TransactionError::Custom(e)),
        TransactionError::Mongodb(e) => {
          if !e.contains_label(mongodb::error::TRANSIENT_TRANSACTION_ERROR) {
            return Err(TransactionError::Mongodb(e));
          } else {
            continue 'run;
          }
        }
      },

      Ok(v) => {
        'commit: loop {
          match session.commit_transaction().await {
            Ok(()) => return Ok(v),
            Err(e) => {
              if e.contains_label(mongodb::error::UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION_COMMIT_RESULT) {
                continue 'commit;
              } else {
                return Err(TransactionError::Mongodb(e))
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the borrow checker keeps complaining with this message:

```rust
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:8:35
   |
8  |       run_transaction(|mut session| async move {
   |  ______________________------------_^
   | |                      |          |
   | |                      |          return type of closure `impl Future` contains a lifetime `'2`
   | |                      has type `&'1 mut ClientSession`
9  | |         let document = collection().find_one_with_session(None,  None, &mut session).await?.unwrap();
10 | |         let r: Result<Document, TransactionError<Never>> = Ok(document);
11 | |         return r;
12 | |     });
   | |_____^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

Is there a way I can solve this?

Comment: By declaring `'a` as a generic to the function you are forcing it to outlive any local variable. Try with `where for <'a> F: Clone + FnOnce(&'a mut ClientSession) -> Fut + 'a, Fut: Future<Output = Result<T, TransactionError<E>>>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Sadly it wont compile, I dont understand why but it says that lifetime 1 will outlive lifetime 2 but they are the same lifetime.. i really dont get it

Comment: Can you this new code that doesn't compile, maybe editing the question?

Comment: @rodrigo I edit the question, adding your suggestion and providing a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Not having a minimum compilable example makes things hard... but I've just wrote a mocked version of your code [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=317cef96c80142ff04717f530a0b2791), with `async fn run_transaction<'a, T, E, F, Fut>(...) where F: Fn(&'a mut ClientSession) -> Fut + 'a, ...`. Can you check that?

Comment: Rodrigo, first of all thank you for the help, your code does compile because you wiped away the implementations, if you put the implementation of `run_transaction` it wont compile saying that there's two `&mut` refs to the `session` at the same time, the implementation do compile with `for<'a>...` but once you call it it wont compile any more, all you have to do to test the example I provided locally is add `mongodb="2"` to you `Cargo.toml` dependencies, and copy the code to `src/main.rs`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you really need is something like:

```
pub async fn run_transaction<T, E, F, Fut>(f: F) -> Result<T, TransactionError<E>> 
  where
    for<'a>
        F: Fn(&'a mut ClientSession) -> Fut,
        Fut: Future<Output = Result<T, TransactionError<E>>> + 'a {
```

Unfortunately this does not work because the "Higer Rank Trait Bound" (HRTB) defined in `for<'a>` only applies to the very next bound, not to every one of them, and there is no way to connect both lifetimes...

But not everything is lost! I've found this [question](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/higher-rank-trait-bounds-use-bound-lifetime-in-another-generic/45121) in the Rust support forum with a similar problem, that can be adapted to your issue. The basic idea is that you create a trait that wraps the `Fn` and the `Future` bounds with the same lifetime:

```
pub trait XFn<'a, I: 'a, O> {
  type Output: Future<Output = O> + 'a;
  fn call(&self, session: I) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<'a, I: 'a, O, F, Fut> XFn<'a, I, O> for F
where
  F: Fn(I) -> Fut,
  Fut: Future<Output = O> + 'a,
{
  type Output = Fut;
  fn call(&self, x: I) -> Fut {
      self(x)
  }
}
```

And now your bound function is trivial:

```
pub async fn run_transaction<T, E, F>(f: F) -> Result<T, TransactionError<E>>
  where for<'a>
        F: XFn<'a, &'a mut ClientSession, Result<T, TransactionError<E>>>
```

Just remember that to call the function you have to write `f.call(&mut session)`.

Unfortunately, the call to `run_transaction()`, as it is, does not compile, saying that *implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough*. I think that it is a limitation/bug of the `async move` as async closures are unstable. But you can instead use a proper async function:

```
    async fn do_the_thing(session: &mut ClientSession) -> Result<Document, TransactionError<Never>> {
      let document = collection().find_one_with_session(None,  None, session).await?.unwrap();
      let r: Result<Document, TransactionError<Never>> = Ok(document);
      return r;
    }
    run_transaction(do_the_thing).await;
```

---

If you think that this is too complicated, and you don't mind paying the very small runtime price there is a simpler option: you can box the returned future, avoiding the second generic altogether:

```
pub async fn run_transaction<T, E, F>(f: F) -> Result<T, TransactionError<E>>
  where for<'a>
        F: Fn(&'a mut ClientSession) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<T, TransactionError<E>>> + 'a>>
```

And then, to call it:

```
    run_transaction(|mut session| Box::pin(async move {
        let document = collection().find_one_with_session(None,  None, session).await?.unwrap();
        let r: Result<Document, TransactionError<Never>> = Ok(document);
        return r;
    }));
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks. There are two things I figured out when implementing this, maybe it is helpful to others.

When using `FnOnce` instead of `Fn`, you will need to make the `call` method use `self` instead of `&self`, it is consumes the function.

Second, although `async {}` indeed doesn't work due to the error mentioned, you can keep this closer by using a syntax like:

```rust
run_transaction({

  async fn do_the_thing() { … }

  do_the_thing

}).await;
```

Basically you define a local function, and return it. Keeps the code closer to the location you might expect.