# How do I use an higher order async function to filter a Vec?

Tags: rust, higher-order-functions

#### Filtering via `async` predicate, the "easy" way

One way would be to `join_all!()` the `Future`s that compute the filters on every item. And then filters synchronously based on those:

```rust
let arr = vec![...]
let filters = join_all!(arr.iter().map(|it| async { predicate(it).await })
let filtered = arr.enumerate().filter(|index, item| filters[index]).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

However, exploring Rust, there's a **cleaner** way via `futures::stream::iter` iterators:

```rust
let filtered = futures::stream::iter(vec![...])
  .filter(|item| async { predicate(item).await })
  .collect::<Vec<_>>
  .await
```

All good up to now.

---

#### Configurable filter: trouble begins

What if we want to use a functional API to make the `predicate` easily configurable?

In that case, our calls will look like:

```rust
let filtered = futures::stream::iter(vec![...])
  .filter(by_length(4)) // neat!
  .collect::<Vec<_>>
  .await
```

And the predicate:

```rust
fn by_length(min_length: usize) -> impl FnMut(&i32) -> Future<Output = bool> {
    |n| async { query_length(n).await > min_length }
}

async fn query_length(n: &i32) -> usize {
    // pretend we're making a network request to fetch `len`...
    // for easy reproducibility's sake this will work here
    n.to_string().len()
}
```

Unfortunately compiler is not happy anymore: it complains the Future needs `dyn` keyword. And, after adding `dyn`, it complains it's not `Sized`, as in this minimal reproduction:

```rust
use futures::future::Future;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let arr = vec![10, 100, 1000];
    
    let filtered = futures::stream::iter(arr.into_iter())
      .filter(by_length(3))
      .collect::<Vec<_>>()
      .await;
      
    println!("{:?}", filtered); // should print [100, 1000]
}

fn by_length(min_length: usize) -> impl FnMut(&i32) -> Future<Output = bool> {
    |n| async { query_length(n).await > min_length }
}

// yeah it doesn't need to be async in this case, but let's pretend
async fn query_length(n: &i32) -> usize {
    n.to_string().len()
}
```

The error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn futures::Future<Output = bool> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
16 |     |n| async { query_length(n).await > min_length }
   |         ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn futures::Future<Output = bool> + 'static)`
   = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size
```

---

#### Questions

- So how can the filter predicate be made configurable?
- From what I gather, the `dyn` keyword requested by the compiler here is to make it explicit it will rely automatic dispatch, incurring in additional overhead.
  However we only need a single typed case here, for which we should be able to generate inline-able machine code. How can Rust be instructed to do that?

Comment: Please consider editing your minimal example to better reflect the problem you are trying to solve, i.e. change `i32` to a non-`Copy` struct. I believe my answer covers the question as written. For example, [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b4cd3c10340cf3ac2ac9fedfe1b8e943).

Comment: @user4815162342 closed, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can't return an `impl Future` from an `impl FnMut`, you can return a boxed future, i.e. a `dyn Future` which must be boxed because it's in return position. After a bit of borrow checker tetris, we arrive to this:

```
fn by_length(min_length: usize) -> impl FnMut(&i32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = bool>>> {
    move |&n| Box::pin(async move { query_length(&n).await > min_length })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f11886d900c9d8fcaeee22b89ec23a33)

---

> However we only need a single typed case here, for which we should be able to generate inline-able machine code. How can Rust be instructed to do that?

I don't think that's currently possible, at least not if you're invoking an `async fn` like `query_length()`. Consider a manually written implementation:

```
fn by_length(min_length: usize) -> impl FnMut(&i32) -> ByLength {
    move |&n| ByLength { n }
}
```

Now, how do we define `ByLength`? It must implement `Future`, and its `poll()` simply transmits the result of polling `query_length(n)`. But the future returned by `query_length(n)` could suspend multiple times, so `ByLength` must *store* the future so it can poll it as many times as needed - for example:

```
struct ByLength {
    n: i32,
    query_fut: Option<???>,
}

impl Future for ByLength {
    type Output = usize;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<usize> {
        if self.query_fut.is_none() {
            self.query_fut = Some(query_length(self.n));
        }
        self.query_fut.unwrap().poll(cx)
    }
}
```

But now the problem becomes apparent: there is no type to substitute for `???` because `query_length()` is an async function which returns a future of an anonymous type. Making `ByLength` generic doesn't work because then we're back at the problem that a closure can't return a generic type that it provides. The signature we'd like would require higher-kinded types:

```
fn by_length(min_length: usize) -> impl for<T> FnMut(&i32) -> ByLength<T> {
    move |&n| ByLength { n }
}
```

...but if we had that, we could just use `query_length()` directly:

```
fn by_length(min_length: usize) -> impl for<T: Future<Output = usize>> FnMut(&i32) -> T {
    move |&n| async move { by_length(&n) }
}
```

Comment: It works! I tried to use the Box before posting but couldn't figure out all of the pointer and move stuff. If we're using a pointer, we do we need to worry about move? After all we're not copying/cloning anything, right?

Comment: You're copying `min_length`

Comment: And you are copying `n` too. What I don't quite understand is why in the original OP code, `.filter(|item| async { predicate(item).await })` works with an `item` of type reference, but if you try using `|n|` as a reference in `query_length` without cloning the `i32` it fails...

Comment: @rodrigo which I am trying right now, as I am not using i32's IRL so I want to avoid copying an expensive struct. If you find anything, please post!

Comment: @doplumi: Take a look at this recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70884778/865874) of mine. But here the final problem are the bounds in [impl Stream for futures::Filter](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.19/futures/stream/struct.Filter.html#impl-Stream), so there is no easy solution that I can see.

Comment: @doplumi: Naturally if you renounce to using `StreamExt::filter()` and write the loop manually it is quite [easy](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc0850790f70aeffe91c7b7aa4ab9b5f).

Comment: The items are not used in the callback after they're sent there: we `.await` before they go out of scope. Yet, Rust is not happy: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f11886d900c9d8fcaeee22b89ec23a33