# Problem passing an async function item as parameter in Rust

Tags: function, asynchronous, generics, rust

[Edit: Updated provided code and compiler error to be easely reproduced]

I'm trying to pass an async function item as parameter to an other function in Rust but it won't compile, providing a cryptic error.

Here is the code I'm trying to compile.

Structure definition (implemented in one crate)

```rust
pub struct FirstTestComponent {
    table: Vec<String>,
    counter: usize,
}

impl FirstTestComponent {
    fn render(&mut self) {
        // Some other irrelevant code
        record_callback(
            FirstTestComponent::add_component,
        );
    }
}

pub struct Services {}

impl FirstTestComponent {

    async fn add_component(&mut self, _: &mut Services) {

        let counter = self.counter;
        self.table.push(counter.to_string());
        self.counter += 1;
    }
}   


pub fn record_callback<F, Fut>(callback: F)
    where 
        F: 'static + Copy + FnOnce(&mut FirstTestComponent, &mut Services) -> Fut,
        Fut: core::future::Future<Output = ()>  + 'static
        {
        }

fn main() {

}
```

When compiling this code, I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:9:9
   |
9  | /         record_callback(
10 | |             FirstTestComponent::add_component,
11 | |         );
   | |_________^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected trait `for<'r, 's> <for<'r, 's> fn(&'r mut FirstTestComponent, &'s mut Services) -> impl for<'r, 's> std::future::Future<Output = ()> {FirstTestComponent::add_component} as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut FirstTestComponent, &'s mut Services)>>`
              found trait `for<'r, 's> <for<'r, 's> fn(&'r mut FirstTestComponent, &'s mut Services) -> impl for<'r, 's> std::future::Future<Output = ()> {FirstTestComponent::add_component} as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut FirstTestComponent, &'s mut Services)>>`
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/main.rs:30:79
   |
30 |         F: 'static + Copy + FnOnce(&mut FirstTestComponent, &mut Services) -> Fut,
   |                                                                               ^^^
```

literally saying that something is different than itself...

I guess there is some error linked to the lifetime hidden in the error message but I can't figure it out.

What could cause this error ? What is wrong with what I've implemented ?

Comment: Please provide a **minimal reproducible** example, stripping any unrelated code and providing all types and functions etc. necessary for the code to (not) compile.

Comment: Please also put the full compiler error, you posted only part of it.

Comment: Does `add_component()` really needs to be async, or you could make it sync and it is async just because it was forced on you by the crate you're using it in as callback?

Comment: Hi !
I didn't provide full example because I generate some part of it with procedural macros and it wasn't so easy to extract needed code.
add_component must be async.

Comment: Just edited original post for anybody to reproduce the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [How to bind lifetimes of Futures to fn arguments in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70746671/how-to-bind-lifetimes-of-futures-to-fn-arguments-in-rust)

The problem as I understand it is this:
From https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html:

> Unlike traditional functions, async fns which take references or other non-'static arguments return a Future which is bounded by the lifetime of the arguments

So I had to force the `Fut` lifetime to be shorter than the input parameters lifetime.

The syntax won't let me simply force this by using Higher Ranked Lifetime bounds (as explained in the answer linked above) so I had to use the pattern proposed there: generate a meta `trait` linking lifetimes as this:

```rust
trait XFn<'a, T, S> {
    type Output: Future<Output = ()> + 'a;
    fn call(&self, this: T, services: S) -> Self::Output;
  }
  
  impl<'a, T: 'a, S: 'a, F, Fut> XFn<'a, T, S> for F
  where
    F: 'static + Copy + FnOnce(T, S) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'a,
  {
    type Output = Fut;
    fn call(&self, this: T, services: S) -> Fut {
        self(this, services)
    }
  }
```

Then I can use this trait to constraints lifetime on arguments and Future like this:

```rust
fn record_callback<F>(callback: F)
    where 
            for<'a> F: XFn<'a, &'a mut FirstTestComponent, &'a mut Services> + 'static + Copy,
    {
    }
```

Comment: I thought you cannot change `record_callback()`, as it is from another crate.